# App can't find ble device if it's not cached

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are using **private services** to communicate between an android app and a microchip ble device. Our communication works buuuuuut, we have to "find" the microchip device first in *settings->bluetooth->search for devices* first.

My theory is that the settings does look for devices with private services and caches them. Our app does not find them by looking, but does find them in the *cache*. we can only connect when first filling the cache by looking for devices in the *settings menu*.

**How can we find ble devices and private services without first looking for them in the settings?**

Comment: Are you using StartLeScan or StartDiscovery?

Comment: startLeScan, which should I be using?

Comment: StartLeScan, i use this and I can find the RN4020 with out any problems.